# Peticion POST a Laravel desde MEAN

Tags: javascript, laravel, nodejs, express

Trabajando con MEAN tengo una petición en un script que hace una consulta POST a un servidor externo, que está desarrollado en Laravel.

**MEAN**

```
var request = require('ajax-request');

request.post({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/API',
    data: {'keywords' : 'hola'},
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
});
```

Y cuando ejecuto el servidor NODE, me sale el siguiente error:

```
request.post({
    ^
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\server\API.js:2:9)
at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\server\index.js:82:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en que estás intentando utilizar la librería externa `jQuery` cuando no la tienes, por eso el error hace referencia al `$`.
Para solucionarlo sin necesidad de importar esta librería, basta con utilizar las funciones nativas:

`document.querySelector("meta[name='_csrf_header']").getAttribute("content")`

Así que quedaría:

```
let request = require('ajax-request'),
    csrfToken = document.querySelector("meta[name='_csrf_header']").getAttribute("content");

request.post({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/API',
    data: {'keywords' : 'hola'},
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken}
});
```

Comment: csrfToken = document.querySelector("meta[name='_csrf_header']").getAttribute("content");
                ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined

este error me muestra

Comment: ¿Este código lo estás ejecutando en un navegador?¿o es desde el servidor Node? Si es el primer caso, el require no funcionará porque JS no sabe 'entrelazar' ficheros de manera nativa. Si es el segundo caso, ni lo que puse yo, ni lo que intentas tú funcionará, pues tanto jQuery como document hacen referencia a la DOM, es decir, la estructura HTML de la página